# Como fazer o texto sumir e aparecer?

Tags: jquery

Não domino jQuery completamente, tenho um texto em uma `div` e gostaria que ele fizesse um efeito de sumir e aparecer como uma apresentação... ou algo parecido.

Mais ou menos assim:

[aparece em 2 segundos]

TEXTO 1

[aguarda 5 segundos]

[some em 2 segundos]

[aparece em 2 segundos]

TEXTO 2

[aguarda 5 segundos]

[some em 2 segundos]

[aparece em 2 segundos]

TEXTO 3

[aguarda 5 segundos]

[some em 2 segundos]

Loop infinito.

Código html:

```html
<div id="texto" class="header_title">
    <h2>TEXTO AQUI</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Isso pode ajudar: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá, se entendi direito, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira.

Com o método [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp), você pode repetir os comandos desejados após um determinado tempo.

```
        setInterval(function(){
            $("#texto").fadeIn(ducarao).delay(tempo);
            $("#texto").fadeOut(duracao);
        }, tempo);
```

Para selecionar a DIV via Jquery você pode utilizar o [seletor](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) $("#texto"), selecionando assim o elemento pela sua ID. Em seguida com a função fadeIn() é realizada a animação de "aparecimento" do texto, perceba também que é possível passar para a função o tempo da animação. A função delay() para manter o texto na tela por 5 segundos e por fim a função fadeOut() para fazer o texto desaparecer.
Recomendo que de umas pesquisada nessas funções no google, já que não posso compartilhar os links das mesmas por não possuir reputação suficiente...

```js
$(function(){
  $("#texto").hide();
});

var i = 2;
setInterval(function(){
 $("#texto").fadeIn(2000).delay(5000);
 $("#texto").fadeOut(2000, function(){
  $("#texto").html("<h2>TEXTO "+ i +"</h2>");
  i++;
 });
}, 2000);
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <div id="texto" class="header_title">
     <h2>TEXTO 1</h2>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Boa sorte!

Comment: Boa tarde, o efeito é esse mesmo, mas a cada transação seria um texto diferente, texto 1, texto 2, texto 3...  e não o mesmo texto como vc colocou

Comment: Você quer atualizar o texto dessa mesma div ou quer mostrar de outra?

Comment: Mesma div, como expliquei lá em cima

Comment: Então, apenas altere o conteúdo da div como fiz na resposta. Você pode usar .html()

Comment: O texto 1 , 2 e 3 são textos de exemplos, o texto serão algo do tipo Texto1='Bem vindo', Texto2='vc esta bem', Texto3='quero comprar etc',